# How to migrate the data between two SharePoint Farms?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to perform the data migration between two SharePoint farms located on the same active directory. I don't know on how to migrate the data from one SharePoint from to another new SharePoint Farm

Comment: both sharepoint versions are same?

Comment: I would like to know what would happend in if one is 2007 and other is 2010 and what if they are same? Singh, please elaborate in details. I'm already impress by your SP skills :)

Comment: i wanted to check whether you need migration or just restoration as for restoration you need both farm installations on same versions even a single hot fix is missing chances of restoration as a success would be minimal. but if its across different versions you can opt for one of different migration techniques which are provided by Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental processes will be like this:

Create a new web application in your new WSS server.
Follow the instructions in Move content databases between instances of SQL Server.
However you may not be able to perform all of the steps exactly as written if your previous server farm is not available. The main thing is that you get the most recent backup of the databases restored on your SQL Server, then follow these steps from the linked article:

1. In Central Administration, on the Application Management page, in the SharePoint Web Application Management section, click Content databases.
2. On the Manage Content Databases page, click Add a content database.
3. On the Add Content Database page, type the exact name of the transferred content database, and then click OK.
4. Repeat steps 14 and 15 for each database you are adding. Be sure that you select the correct Web application from the Web Application menu for each database.

I don't know your farm topology but if you are sharing the same SQL Server used for the dead server farm, make sure that the dead farm is completely powered off. You don't want two different SharePoint farms accessing the same data (especially if one is in an inconsistent state).

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of doing this:

1) Backup content database on source farm and restore in target farm, then attach to a web application.

2) Create (i.e. export) a content migration package on the source farm and import on the target farm

3) Set up a content deployment path between the source and target farms (probably not appropriate in this case)

All of these are documented extensively on Technet. If you have custom or third-party code you will need to deploy these to the target server also.

Comment: I agree up to some extent but I would have loved more detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

If the old farm is alive and not in inconsistent state then you will be better off using a migration tool even if the versions of new and old are same.

The reason is that service packs, patches as well as order of their installation causes differences in SharePoint instances which can mess backup-recovery mechanism.

Migration is much more forgiving as it pre-assumes that differences exist between source and destination.

Several migration tools are available with Sharegate being my favourite.